# UnassignedReferenceException even though using the null-conditional operator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null-conditional-operator

I'm getting a `UnassignedReferenceException: The variable _Preset of Foo has not been assigned.` even though I'm using the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) `?.`.

**My code:**

```
// […]
myTarget.Preset?.ApplyTo(myTarget);
```

I'm also noticing that it mentions `_Preset` instead of `Preset` (which I find odd).

**Code in `Foo.cs` :**

```
[CreateAssetMenu()]
public class Foo : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private Preset _Preset = null;

    public Preset Preset
    {
        get { return _Preset; }
        protected set { _Preset = value; }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Isn't it what the operator is for?

Google searches didn't help.

Comment: `UnassignedReferenceException` is not the same thing as `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Looks like a Unity specific thing, seems to be a few simple answers if you search for `UnassignedReferenceException`

Comment: If you remove the null-conditional operator and try to use it directly like `myTarget.Preset.ApplyTo(myTarget);`, What happens? Any error?

Comment: @Programmer Same error with and without it. (Only when I don't specify a value in the Inspector that is, as expected)

Comment: I thought the problem is still there even when initialized from the Editor. I suggest you just use `== nll` or `!= null`. If that works, stick with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unity has a custom way to check inspector's references against null.](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/)

> When a MonoBehaviour has fields, in the editor only[1], we do not set those fields to “real null”, but to a “fake null” object. Our custom == operator is able to check if something is one of these fake null objects, and behaves accordingly

They may not have overloaded the null-conditional operator. Your `get` property returns the "fake null" explaining your unassigned error (and not the NullReferenceException).

> The custom null check also comes with a bunch of downsides.
>   It behaves inconsistently with the ?? operator, which also does a null check, but that one does a pure c# null check, and cannot be bypassed to call our custom null check.

I guess the same problem occurs for the null-conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

As a late update and if you have the possibility to, you should definitely use the [ReSharper Extension for Unity](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity).

Among other neat features, whenever it can, **ReShaper for Unity** will warn you if you are trying to use an operator you shouldn't on an Unity object.